# i tried autoplot with the output of glm but i get this error. Ps: i tried to install "ggfortify" but it doesn't solve the problem for me

Tags: r

```
nb <- glm.nb(N_caouanne_mois ~ Golfe:cos(PseudoFourrier) + Golfe:sin(PseudoFourrier) + Effort_jours_mois.Rescaled + Longueur.des.bras.Rescaled + Longueur.du.bourrelet.Rescaled + Longueur.de.la.corde.de.dos.Rescaled + Taille.de.maille.cul.du.sac.Rescaled + Ouverture.verticale.Rescaled + Longueur.panneau..m.Rescaled + Duree.du.trait.Rescaled + Longueur.de.la.corde.de.dos.Rescaled + Golfe,
             ,na.action = "na.omit", data = NewChalutUnfold)
autoplot(nb)
```

> Erreur : Objects of type negbin/glm/lm not supported by autoplot.
> Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) and update your question.

Comment: did you *load* `ggfortify` as well as installing it?  (You should probably add your "PS" to the body of your question rather than the title ...)

Answer (score 2):

Try

- installing the `ggfortify` package (via `install.packages("ggfortify")`) [you only need to do this once per computer/installation of R] and
- loading it (via `library("ggfortify")`)

then retry your `autoplot()` command.

Comment: You are correct, I tried an example after posting my (incorrect) answer and deleted mine once I realized you were right.